# Christmas light driver, two wires, 24V

Tags: led, ws2812b

I've got a Christmas led chain ( a waterfall actually ) with some troubles so I tryed to look at it... it has an only two wire bus, with a DC 24V i can measure on. I read about the `ws 2812` being sort of standard for such applications ( please correct me if I'm wrong ) but, even if in the datasheet I can see a two wire daisy chain ( basically each led has a resistor/capacitor to use the signal as a power supply, so this allow for two wire only `Signal+Vcc/GND`, but what looks strange to me is the fact that signal should "desy chains" between each chip, so how can a 24v be feed into a chip pin? I verified at the end of the chain, and yes we still have 24 v so no internal/hidden voltage regulators